# Nesting List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I frequently run into a problem where I'm trying to make a list of lists of a certain length from a string.

This is an example where I have a string, but would like to make a list of lists of length 3:

```
x = '123456789'

target_length = 3

new = [i for i in x]
final = [new[i:i+target_length] for i in range(0, len(x), target_length)]

print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

So, this works, but feels so clunky.

Is there a better way to combine these arguments into one line or do you think that would make the code unreadable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in one line you can just create the lists inside your comprehension:

```
x = '123456789'
target_length = 3

[list(x[i:i+target_length]) for i in range(0, len(x), target_length)]
>> [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it in one line:

```
f2 = [[x[(j * target_length) + i] for i in range(target_length)] for j in range(target_length)]
```

Comment: This assumes that the length of the list is `target_length**2`, which it is in this example, but only coincidentally.

Comment: True.  AK47's answer is the better one

Comment: You could fix or at least improve it by using `range(len(x) // target_length)` in the outer loop, then it works at least for lengths of `x` that are a multiple of the target length.